# Declare a pointer to different class in member funcion

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class StudentClass{
friend class Oopclass;
public:
    StudentClass();
    void setStudentData();
    void printStudentScore();
    StudentClass* next;
    ~StudentClass();
private:
    string std_ID;
    int sID, sMid, sFin, sOP, hw[3];   
    double sTotal; 

};

class OopClass{
friend class StudentClass;
public:
    OopClass();
    void setOopData();
    void printOopScore();
    void queryOopScore();
    void findOopAverageScore();
    void addStudentData();
    void deleteStudentData();
    void updateStudentData();
    ~OopClass();
private:
    string professor, subject;
    int cSn;
    double cSAvg;
    StudentClass* cSAddr;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
OopClass Info[3];
Info[0].setOopData();
return 0;
}

StudentClass::StudentClass(){
}
void StudentClass(){
}
void StudentClass::setStudentData() {

}
StudentClass::~StudentClass(){
}
OopClass::OopClass(){
}
void OopClass::setOopData() {
cout << "Professor?" << endl;
cin >> professor;
cout << "Subject?" << endl;
cin >> subject; 
cout << "How many students do you want to input ?" << endl;
int number = 0;
cin >> number;
cSAddr = new StudentClass;
//for(int i = 0; i < number; i ++) setStudentData();

}
OopClass::~OopClass(){
}
```

When I tired to write "cSAddr = new StudentClass;" ,it come up to

error about

> "  C:\Users\lypan\Documents\final.cpp In member function 'void
>   OopClass::setOopData()':
>
> 63 14 C:\Users\lypan\Documents\final.cpp [Error] expected
>   type-specifier before 'StudentClass'
>
> 63 14 C:\Users\lypan\Documents\final.cpp [Error] invalid conversion
>   from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
>
> 63 14 C:\Users\lypan\Documents\final.cpp [Error] expected ',' or ';'
>   before 'StudentClass'  "

And I have no idea why I do wrong, please tell me what I make mistake. Thx!

Comment: Did you include the header file defining `StudentClass` in the `.cpp` file where you define `OopClass::setOopData`?

Comment: Post the complete code, not arbitrary fragments.

Comment: You have different spelling of the "OopClass" in different places... Is it just copy/paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error here is that you didn't **implement** the constructors for your classes. But that should yield a linker error.

This probably isn't your code, but it might be that you don't include `StudentClass.h` and `OopClass.h` (or whatever) in the file where you define `OopClass::setOopData()`.

EDIT:

```
void StudentClass()
```

you declare a function called `StudentClass` on line 46 - http://codepad.org/9DP6zpHU - you probably forgot to qualify it.

```
StudentClass::StudentClass(){
}
//THIS!
void StudentClass(){
}
void StudentClass::setStudentData() {

}
```

Comment: It's my code and I don't seperate the header. I write to one cpp. I skipp the constructor to make the question more readable.

Comment: @Liang-YuPan see edited answer, you have a function there called `StudentClass()`.

Comment: Oh,What stupid am I! I ama sorry for make the stupid mistake! Thx for your help!

Comment: @Liang-YuPan the only mistake was that it was not the actual code :P Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is you define a function with the same name as the class `StudentClass`:

```
void StudentClass(){
}
```

Remove that function and it should work better.